# Matrix and graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic iff exists a matrix of permutations $P$ such that $A_{G'}=PA_{G}P^{T}$
Note: A matrix $P$ is called *matrix of permutations* if its entries are $0$ and $1$ and each row and column contains precisely  one "$1$"

Answer (score 4):

Two graphs are isomorphic if there is an isomorphism $f$ between their sets of vertices such that the connectivities are preserved, i.e.,

$$f\!:\ V(G) \to V(G'), \quad \{u,v\} \in E(G) \Leftrightarrow \{f(u),f(v)\} \in E(G').$$

Since sets $V(G) = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ and $V(G') = \{v'_1,\dots,v'_n\}$ are finite, this means that $f$ is a permutation. Let $P$ be a matrix with elements $p_{ij}$ such that

$$p_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1, & j = f(i), \\
0, & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}$$
and let $A_G$ (with elements $a_{ij}$) be adjacency matricx of G$. We define

$$A_{G'} = P A_G P^T.$$

Descriptively, this translates $i$-th row and $j$-th column of $A_G$ to $f(i)$-th row and $f(j)$-th column of $A_{G'}$. In other words, denoting the elements of $A_{G'}$ as $a'_{ij}$, note that

$$a'_{f(i),f(j)} = (P A_G P^T)_{f(i),f(j)} = a_{ij},$$

which shows that $A_{G'}$ is the adjacency matrix of $G'$.